# Python Dataframe subtract a value from each list of a row

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, numpy

I have a data frame consisting of lists as elements. I want to subtract a value from each list and create a new column.
My code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[[1,2],[4,5,6]]})
df
           A
0     [1, 2]
1  [4, 5, 6]

# lets substract 1 from each list
val = 1
df['A_new'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x:[a-b for a,b in zip(x[0],[val]*len(x[0]))],axis=1)
```

Present solution:

```
IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2
```

Expected solution:

```
df
           A      A_new
0     [1, 2]     [0, 1]
1  [4, 5, 6]  [3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert to `numpy` `array`

```
df['A_new'] = df.A.map(np.array)-1
Out[455]: 
0       [0, 1]
1    [3, 4, 5]
Name: A, dtype: object
```

Comment: One more question: how can I identify the index of minimum in each list? Like `A_new_min = [0,0]` (here 0 is minimum in first list, 3 in second list; both these are in 0 index). Thanks

Comment: @Mainland `(df.A.map(np.array)-1).map(np.argmin)
` argmin

Comment: Suppose there are positive and negative values. I might want to do the `abs()` here. Will this be correct? `(df.A.map(np.array)-1).map(abs()).map(np.argmin)`?

Comment: @Mainland `(df.A.map(np.array)-1).map(np.abs).map(np.argmin)
`

Comment: Is `map` a better solution compared to the `apply(lambda x:  ....for.....)` approach? I mean, is `map` a vectorized approach compared to the `apply(lambda x:...` ?

Comment: I posted one more question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72078621/python-dataframe-process-two-columns-of-lists-and-find-minimum

Answer (score 2):

```
df['A_new'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x:[a-b for a,b in zip(x,[val]*len(x))])
```

You have to pass the list to the `len` function. Here `x` is the list itself. So indexing it, `x[0]` just returns a number which is wrong given the context. This gives the output:

```
           A      A_new
0     [1, 2]     [0, 1]
1  [4, 5, 6]  [3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

How about a simple list comprehension:

```
df['new'] = [[i - 1 for i in l] for l in df['A']]
```

---

```
           A        new
0     [1, 2]     [0, 1]
1  [4, 5, 6]  [3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the list to `np.array` and then subtract the `val`:

```
import numpy as np

df['A_new'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x: np.array(x) - val)
```

Output:

```
           A      A_new
0     [1, 2]     [0, 1]
1  [4, 5, 6]  [3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: One more question: how do you find the index of minimum in the `A_new` in the same code? I tried this `lambda x: np.argmin(np.array(x) - val)` but not giving correct answer.

Comment: @Mainland It works correctly for me did you use this `df['A_new'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x: np.argmin(np.array(x) - val))`?